# ActiveX Standard user support

Tags: c++, com, activex

By redirecting the registry entries of HKLM and HKCR to HKCU, I converted my per-machine ActiveX to per-user ActiveX. Now I can install my activeX even from a standard user. Now I want to mark my ActiveX control safe for Initializing and scripting. I tried [this](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/161873). But I was thrown "Access Denied" error while marking the control safe for scripting from any user who is not a local administrator. I found my dllRegisterServer method making some registry entries in HKCR to mark my ocx as safe for scripting and initializing. So I did the following redirection from HKLM to HKCU in the following method.

```
HRESULT RegisterCLSIDInCategory(REFCLSID clsid, CATID catid)
{
HKEY key;
if ( aboveXP )
{
    if ( ERROR_SUCCESS != ::RegOpenKeyW(HKEY_CURRENT_USER, L"Software\\Classes", &key) )
    {
        return E_FAIL;
    }
    if ( ERROR_SUCCESS != ::RegOverridePredefKey(HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT, key) )
    {
        ::RegCloseKey(key);
        return E_FAIL;
    }       
}

// Register your component categories information.
ICatRegister* pcr = NULL ;
HRESULT hr = S_OK ;
hr = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_StdComponentCategoriesMgr,
    NULL,
    CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER,
    IID_ICatRegister,
    (void**)&pcr);
if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
{
    // Register this category as being "implemented" by
    // the class.
    CATID rgcatid[1] ;
    rgcatid[0] = catid;
    hr = pcr->RegisterClassImplCategories(clsid, 1, rgcatid);

    if(FAILED(hr))
    {
        sprintf ( log , "RegisterClassImplCategories failed with error %lu" , hr ) ;
        MessageBox ( NULL , log , _T("ClassImplCategories Failed" ) , MB_OK ) ;
    }

}
else
{
    sprintf ( log , "CO-CREATE-INSTANCE failed with error %lu" , hr ) ;
    MessageBox ( NULL , log , _T("CoCreateInstance Failed" ) , MB_OK ) ;

    _com_error err(hr);
    LPCTSTR errMsg = err.ErrorMessage();
    MessageBox ( NULL , errMsg , _T("CO-CREATE-INSTANCE failed - Error Message") , MB_OK ) ;
}


if (pcr != NULL)
    pcr->Release();

if ( aboveXP )
{
    ::RegCloseKey ( key ) ;
}
MessageBox ( NULL , "RETUNING FROM SAFE FOR SCRIPTING" , "TEST" , MB_OK ) ;
return hr;}
```

Now my "Access denied" problem is solved, but when I install this new per-user version I am prompted for restart. I doubt I am redirecting a registry entry which has to be in HKLM to HKCU.

The following entries are made in HKCR while marking an OCX control as safe for scripting.

HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Component
   Categories{7DD95801-9882-11CF-9FA9-00AA006C42C4}

HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Component
   Categories{7DD95802-9882-11CF-9FA9-00AA006C42C4}

HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID{"your controls GUID"}\Implemented
   Categories{7DD95801-9882-11CF-9FA9-00AA006C42C4}

HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID{"your controls GUID"}\Implemented
   Categories{7DD95802-9882-11CF-9FA9-00AA006C42C4}

I have no problem in creating first two entries even without redirection. But when my control tries to create the last two from non local admin account I get access denied. At the same time I could find the first two entries, even if I register my ocx from a standard user account.

What is going on at the back end while marking my ocx safe for scripting ?
Why am I prompted for restart and How can I avoid it ?
What am I doing wrong ?
How can I mark my per-user activeX control safe for scripting ?

I refered [this](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/161873)

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: This comment is safe to upvote.

Comment: Have your object implement `IObjectSafety`, and in particular `GetInterfaceSafetyOptions`. This way you can mark it safe without having to create any additional registry entries.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Thanks a lot. I implemented IObjectSafety interface and it worked fine. Now I could invoke my activex control from all the accounts with out any prompt for restart. But when I run IE as administrator ( by right clicking run as admin ), I could install my cab but my activex control is not getting called. However it works fine when I run IE normally without any elevation. When I examine my registry I could see the following key. HKCU\software\Microsoft\windows\currentversion\ext\stats\{my guid}\iexplore\blocked=4[dword]. What is blocking my active x control ? Thanks in advance.